# How much does the sky weigh?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, pressure, atmospheric-science, weight

How much does the sky weigh?

I don't know how much the sky weighs. Is the sky gravity?

I tried researching, but I can't find scientific information that is proven.

Answer (score 9):

> How much does the sky weigh ?

The only meaningful interpretation I can think of is that the question is meant to be

> What is the weight of the Earth’s atmosphere ?

You can estimate this once you know that the Earth’s average atmospheric pressure at sea level is approximately $14.7$ pounds per square inch or $101,000$ Newtons per square metre (you also need to know the surface area of the Earth).

Comment: Hint: it's a BIG number.